# Using mongoose $inc in array of subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to implement a functionality where every product posted will increase product counts of respective category and subcategory.
This is my schema:

```
//Subcategory
const subcategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String},
    productsCounts: {type: Number, default: 0},
});

//Category
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String},
    subcategories: [subcategorySchema],
    productsCounts: {type: Number, default: 0}
});

//Method I use to update products count
categorySchema.statics.increaseProductsCounts = function (categoryId, subcategoryId) {
    //Increase category's productCounts.
    this.findByIdAndUpdate(categoryId, {$inc: {productsCounts: 1}}).then(r => {
        console.log(r)
    });
};
```

The above code works for category productCounts well. How can update specific subcategory productCounts too?

Comment: I am beginner To mongoDb and mongoose. That question didnt help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) (MongoDB 3.6 or newer) to define a condition which will identify your `subcategory`:

```
categorySchema.statics.increaseProductsCounts = function (categoryId, subcategoryId) {
    this.findByIdAndUpdate(categoryId, 
        {$inc: {productsCounts: 1, 'subcategories.$[sub].productsCounts': 1}}, 
        { arrayFilters:[ { 'sub._id': subcategoryId } ] }).then(r => {
            console.log(r);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I have copied and pasted the above code in my project but only productsCounts in **Category** increases and not in specific subcategory. Here is the log i get `{ productsCounts: 108,
  _id: 5c8ab97c4835f2316811d41d,
  title: 'Guests',
  subcategories:
   [ { productsCounts: 0,
       properties: [],
       _id: 5c8ab99d4835f2316811d41e,
       title: 'Bondeni' },
     { productsCounts: 0,
       properties: [],
       _id: 5c8ab9ba4835f2316811d420,
       title: 'Tema' } ],
  __v: 0 }`

Comment: What could still be wrong?

Comment: After updating mongoose version to latest it now works. Thanks for

Comment: can you take a look at my other question. they are kind related. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217447/mongoose-upsert-and-inc-subdocument) @mickl